# Dynamically resolve icon font code in a SCSS rule

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js, icon-fonts

I am using `Nuxt.js` (https://nuxtjs.org/), `Vuetify.js` (https://vuetifyjs.com/) and `@mdi/font` (https://materialdesignicons.com/) icon font.

I have a case where I want to use an icon, but not the normal way as I normally do in HTML, e.g.

```
<v-icon>
  mdi-check
</v-icon>
```

but I want to use `mdi-check` in a SCSS rule (no icon-related html code), so I guess that what I need is dynamically resolving its `content` code, e.g.

```
&:before {
  font-family: Material Design Icons;
  content: 'here I need to dynamically access the code of the "mdi-check" icon, which is "\F012C"';
}
```

it is important to me not having to put the static code (`\F012C`), because it may change in the future, but I would like to find a way to dynamically resolve it.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do like this.

```
<v-icon data-icon="\F012C">
  mdi-check
</v-icon>
```

then in css

```
&:before {
  font-family: Material Design Icons;
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Thanks

Comment: thank you, but I knew about that and in my case I dont want to use the custom html, I just need the SCSS rule :(. Just because I don't want to rely on the static icon code value and want to use that icon without knowing its code.